# Get timezone in R from Linux server

Tags: r, linux, datetime

I'm facing problem to get timezone of Linux server from R code. See code below, what I was given is:

```
Sys.time()

[1] "2016-03-18 11:20:11 IST"

Sys.timezone()

[1] NA
```

In the above situation I got timezone including with date and time, when I was given Sys.time(). But individually I couldn't get timezone.

I want timezone of Linux server with out setting timezone.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem sometimes with `Sys.timezone()`. The result depends on settings of the system, and the OS may run on a different locale than R. In any case, I obtain the same `NA` result on my Linux machine.

As a workaround, try

```
format(Sys.time(), format="%Z")
```

or

```
as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())$zone
```